# postgres count distinct values from multiple column

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, multiple-columns

I am trying to display all different values from 3 columns and the amount of them.

My table:

```
date |  col1  |  col2  | col3
-------------------------------
26...|  a     |  a     | b
25...| c      |  d     |  a
...
```

All 3 columns have the values a, b, c, d.

I would like to have something like this:

```
date   |  col  |  a  | b   |  c  |   d 
--------------------------------------
26.....| col1  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0
26.....| col2  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  0
26.....| col3  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  0
25.....| col1  |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0
25.....| col2  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  1
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Assuming that the possible values are fixed (`a`,`b`,`c` and `d`), an alternative is to create a row for each column and date in a `CTE` and in the outer query count them with a `FILTER`, e.g.

```
WITH j (date,col) AS (
  SELECT date, unnest(array[col1,col2,col3])
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT j.date, 'col'||j.col, 
 count(*) FILTER (WHERE col ='a'), 
 count(*) FILTER (WHERE col ='b'),
 count(*) FILTER (WHERE col ='c'),
 count(*) FILTER (WHERE col ='d') 
FROM j
JOIN mytable t ON t.date = j.date
GROUP BY j.date,j.col
ORDER BY j.date,j.col;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=521033aec788a4d785df964d8eee2ab9)

Comment: Not exctly. The column names col1, col2, col3 should be seen in the second table in the column col.

Comment: @hm5 I see. So I believe you'll need to write a dynamic query for that. Can you share what you've tried so far? Perhaps with a few input from your side we can speed things up-

Comment: I tried something simpler, but I can only count one value. Also it doesn't include for witch value the count are:      SELECT * FROM ( date, COUNT(*) FILTER( WHERE col1 = 'a'), COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE col2 = 'a'), COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE col3 = 'a') FROM mytable GROUP BY date) FROM mytable

Comment: the table then shows a column date, a column col1, a column col2 ans a column col3